# Library needs to store object in a Web session: suggestions on API design

Tags: python, openid, api-design

I'm developing an OpenID consumer library [[1](https://github.com/isagalaev/sm-openid)] that does its job in two separate Web requests:

1. When user requests authentication the library discovers some information from a URL provided by the user.
2. This information is used during another Web request when the library actually finishes authentication.

I want an advice on how best to design the library API for persisting the "discovery information" between two requests:

1. I could ask the caller to provide their own session object for both calls and the library would store and read its own object from it:

   ```
   result = openid.request(session, url) # stores discovery in `session`
   # ...
   openid.authenticate(session, auth_data) # reads discovery from `session`
   ```

   I don't really like it aesthetically as it looks like an Inversion of Control: bring your own buffer, we'll use it for you. Also, a "session" is not a well-defined interface and may expose some limitations. For example, sessions in Django by default only want to store JSON-serializable objects and the object representing the discovery information is of a custom class that json doesn't recognize.
2. I could return the discovery info to the caller and let them deal with it as they see fit:

   ```
   result, discovery = openid.request(url)
   session['openid.discovery'] = discovery
   # ...
   openid.authenticate(session['openid.discovery'], auth_data)
   ```

   This makes the library cleaner (no need to invent session key names or session cleanup policies) but moves this job to the caller. Which is probably okay if the caller is another library code implementing OpenID behaviour for a Web framework, but not okay if the caller is an application developer who shouldn't be bothered with this sort of book-keeping.

Which approach is best (for any subjective definition of "best")? Is there another one?

Comment: Request and authenticate are just functions, right? How about making a class with such method and then store whatever internal session/ other info within the class? This way user doesn't need to know about that state at all. *I am no python expert at all, so this all may not make sense ;)

Comment: Those two calls happen in two different Web requests, they're not guaranteed to be handled by the same process. So, a class won't solve it, as you will have to create a new instance every before calling a method anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Second approach is definitely cleaner, because:

1. normal return values are always better than "out" arguments
2. it doesn't restrict format of you session object (in fact, there may be no explicit session object at all)